# Multivariate Generalisation of Percentile and Likelihood of a Draw

Tags: likelihood, quantiles, multivariate-normal-distribution

Say I have $n$ values which approximate some distribution $D$. If I have a value $x$ and I would like to know how likely it is that $x$ came from $D$, I could simply determine $x$'s *percentile*. By calculating what percentage of the $n$ values is larger/smaller than $x$, I know how *extreme* $x$ is.

1. How does this generalise to multiple dimensions?

Say I have $n$ 2D values. You may assume it is taken from a binormal distibution, as shown in the figure below. The mean is the red dot.

2. How *extreme* / *likely* is the green dot?

[image]

*Mathematica* code to reproduce figure:

```
Needs["MultivariateStatistics`"]
myData=RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[{2,1},{{0.3,-0.15},{-0.15,0.3}}],10^3];
Show[ListPlot[myData,PlotRange->{{0,4},{0,2}}],Graphics[PolytopeQuantile[myData,0.5]],Graphics[{PolytopeQuantile[myData,0.8],{PointSize[Large],Red,Point[{2,1}]},{PointSize[Large],Green,Point[{1.3,1.7}]}}]]
```

The figure includes two [ellipsoids](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/MultivariateStatistics/ref/EllipsoidQuartiles.html) at values $0.5$ and $0.8$, which generalise the concept of Quantiles.

3. Without using trial-and-error, can I determine the ellipsoid which runs through the green dot?

In my case, you may assume the data is normal, unimodal and that the covariance matrix can be determined from the $n$ values. So the following question is a *bonus*:

4. Can this be generalised to multimodal distributions? And how does that relate to [High Density Regions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148439/what-is-a-highest-density-region-hdr)?

And finally:

5. What is the correct nomenclature? Which statistical terms relate to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One measure of *likelihood* of a value is the [Mahalanobis Distance](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2012/02/15/what-is-mahalanacobis-distance.html), which works for arbitrary dimensions.

It must also relate to the multidimensional quantiles, but I am not sure how exactly.

[image]

*Mathematica* code:

```
Needs["MultivariateStatistics`"]
myData=RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[{2,1},{{0.3,-0.15},{-0.15,0.3}}],10^4];
myMean=Mean[myData]
myCovariance=Covariance[myData]
myPoint={1.3,1.7}
mahalanobisDistance[covariance_,vector_,mean_]:=Sqrt[(vector-mean).Inverse[covariance].(vector-mean)]
myDistance=mahalanobisDistance[myCovariance,myPoint,myMean]
myQuantile=CDF[NormalDistribution[],myDistance]
Show[ListPlot[myData,PlotRange->{{0,4},{0,2}}],Graphics[{PolytopeQuantile[myData,myQuantile],{PointSize[Large],Red,Point[myMean]},{PointSize[Large],Green,Point[myPoint]}}]]
```