# Is the boundary of an HDR a region of the sample space with equal density value?

Tags: estimation, highest-density-region

After reading [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148439/what-is-a-highest-density-region-hdr), I read in the reference provided ([Hyndman, 1996, *The American Statistician*](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00031305.1996.10474359?journalCode=utas20#)) the following:

> It follows inmediately from the definition that the boundary of an HDR consists of those values of the sample space with equal density.

How does it follow from the definition ?

> Let $f(x)$ be the density function of a random variable $X$. Then the
>   $100(1-\alpha)\%$ HDR is the subset $R(f_\alpha)$ of the sample space
>   of $X$ such that 
>   $$R(f_\alpha) = \{x\colon f(x)\geq f_\alpha\},$$
>   where $f_\alpha$ is the largest constant such that
>   $$P\big(X\in R(f_\alpha)\big)\geq 1-\alpha.$$

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't, at least not in general. This only holds for continuous densities.

If the density $f$ is continuous, then the boundary of an HDR 
$$R(f_\alpha) = \{x\colon f(x)\geq f_\alpha\}$$
(which is the pre-image of the half-open interval $[f_\alpha,\infty[$ under $f$) is given by $\{x\colon f(x)=f_\alpha\}$.

For a counterexample with a non-continuous density, define

$$ f(x) := \begin{cases}
0, & x<0 \\
\tau, & x=0 \\
\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}, & x>0
\end{cases}$$

This integrates to 1, so it is a density. Every HDR will be of the form $[0,x_\alpha]$, where $x_\alpha>0$ depends on $\alpha$, and obviously, we will typically not have $\tau=f(0)=f(x_\alpha)$.

Alternatively, use any discrete distribution, where this statement will usually also not hold.

Comment: Is it sensible to assign/define a density value to the point of discontinuity in a density function?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings: I don't think it's very useful. If we don't assign it a value, then the density may not even be defined at the boundary of the HDR. (Which already holds at $\infty$.)

Comment: I am a bit puzzled about the *meaning* of such assigned value. It may have a meaning to the mathematicians that only care about functions, but I wonder whether it is correct from the applied point of view. How can you speak about the density in a point of discontinuity? Just using some value because otherwise it would be undefined doesn't sound like a good argument to me.

Comment: Well, we can remove/undefine/redefine a countable number of points from a continuous density, anyway, so one could say that talking about the density's value *at specific points* makes countably infinitely little sense, anyway.

Comment: Another reference, (Meeker and Escobar 1995) , claim there is a "... close relationship between likelihood based confidence intervals and Bayesian highest posterior density (HPD) intervals (e.g., Casella and Berger 1990,
p. 424; Severini 1991)" Does this mean that there is a procedure to establish $f_\alpha$ in relation to the maximum density $f_{MAP}$, based on some ditributional assumptions (like it is done for the likelihood)?

Comment: That doesn't ring a bell. Perhaps you want to post a separate question on that, it's a different topic.